# Sql several rows greater than value of other table

Tags: sql

My model is `A as many B`. These tables are related by `A.id` and `B.item_id`. `B` has a column called `created_at`. I need to select all rows from `A` such that `B.created_at` is greater than 2016-09-1`. I would like to know if it possible to solve that question using a query similar to this one:

```
SELECT * FROM A 
WHERE  (
    (SELECT B.created_at
     FROM B
     WHERE B.item_id = A.id)
    >= '2016-09-1' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `JOIN` and selecting only from `A`:

```
Select  A.*
From    A
Join    B   On  A.id = B.item_id
Where   B.created_at > '2016-09-01'
```

Comment: without join please

Comment: Why without join?  It acts as a filter to only give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.* 
from A 
left join B 
    on B.item_id=A.id
where B.created_at >= '2016-09-1'
```

Answer (score 0):

> need to select from A all rows such that B.created_at is greater than '2016-09-1'

```
select * from A where exists(SELECT 1
     FROM B
     WHERE B.item_id = A.id)
    b.created_at>= '2016-09-1')
```

Answer (score 0):

In general this can be done with an INNER JOIN containing your date filter criteria. Something like:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
  ON A.id = B.Iditem_id
  AND B.created_at > '2016-09-01'
```

This would be a T-SQL method for doing this.

You can also apply a simple WHERE clause - you'd want to check the execution plan to see if either of these options make a real difference...

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
  ON A.id = B.Iditem_id
WHERE B.created_at > '2016-09-01'
```

If you want to use a subset from table B first... you can do...

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN (
             SELECT B.*
             FROM B
             WHERE B.created_at > '2016-09-01')
            )Bsub
  ON A.id = Bsub.Iditem_id
```

All of these would work with T-SQL, can't speak to other SQL-like languages.

Comment: without inner join?

Comment: I can add that too - do you want all the records from table A that are not in table B? If not, then inner join makes the most sense. What are you querying if I can ask? Is this SQL Server, Oracle, mysql etc.? 

-edit: Or are you asking about doing the join using the where clause?